# BeagleBone Black uEnv.txt empty

Tags: ssh, beagleboneblack

I've recently purchased a BeagleBone Black. I installed the drivers, got myself a SD card and an external card reader,7yip and win32 disk imager just like the Beaglebone startup guide told me to. However, when I put my disk on the micro-sd card and insert that into the Beaglebone, I need to tell it to boot from micro-sd.

For that I need to go to the SSH terminal (putty) and type the following:

```
sudo nano boot/uEnv.txt
```

In that I need to remove the # at the start of 
`#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh` 
for it to boot off the SD. The first time I did this, it worked. I was just navigating down to the line of code when putty told me that it has disconnected. The next dozens of times I tried to access uEnv.txt, it was completely empty. I don't know why it crashed, nor have I found out how the hell I get it to work. I have unzipped the original file again and installed a new disk several times now, but it's still empty.

EDIT:
Hmm, I've heard win32 disk seems to be unreliable. I'll attempt to use another program, but I don't think that's the problem. But take this into consideration

Comment: Add this comment in your post by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

I asked a guy I know who has more knowledge in this area. It turns out all this time I was just creating a NEW uEnv.txt file. For all other people who might be struggling with this; The command to **open** the uEnv.txt file is

```
sudo nano ./boot/uEnv.txt
```

The ./ plays a very important role here. From there you can edit the file as you wish.
I hope this helps!